# Events not firing when hosting DataGridView in Winforms Host

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridview, winforms-interop

Im trying to host a Datagridview in a WPF usercontrol. The datagridview is added to the winformshost in the constructor and the Enter and Leave events wired up.
The Enter event fires the first time the grid gets focus but not subsequently and the leave event is never fired.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> Enter and Leave events are not raised when the following focus changes
>   occur:
>
> - From inside to outside a WindowsFormsHost control.
> - From outside to inside a WindowsFormsHost control.
> - Outside a WindowsFormsHost control.
> - From a Windows Forms control hosted in a WindowsFormsHost control to an ElementHost control hosted inside the same WindowsFormsHost.

So if you want the leave and enter events to fire you'd have to leave to another control in the same WindowsFormsHost. This would only be possible by creating a usercontrol containing the datagridview and another control.

Feels like a hack though. If you can, just live with the fact that it's not supported.

Comment: Now why couldn't I find that! I have Hacked around it by firing the "GotFocus" event of the winforms host as the datagridview is the only control and takes up 100% of the space. I don't need to handle the leave event. Thanks a lot